# A library or method to create large numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, public-key-encryption

I'm working on an prime factorization algorithm. To test it I need some large numbers with few and big prime numbers. for example `Number=(BigPrime1*BigPrime2)`.

By `Large Number` I mean as large as the current RSA algorithms uses for key generations.

How can I find some of these numbers to test and challenge my algorithm.

Is there any library for them? or any site already have some numbers for challenge?

Comment: How can you possibly be working on a factoring algorithm for large integers and not *already* be familiar with BigInteger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest known primes are some of [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).  [Lists](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/math/prime/mersenne.html) are available of their decimal expansions which would provide some test data for your algorithm.

There is plenty of other information on large primes.  A good overview can be found [here](http://primes.utm.edu/largest.html).

Of course, if you want to generate a large number of large primes for your test cases, read up on [probable primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probable_prime) as suggested in an earlier answer.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get what you are asking for is to construct the numbers. First pick a set of e.g. three largish [probable primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probable_prime). Multiply them together to get an even larger number that probably has a few large prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

Is BigInteger large enough..?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx